# select2 multiple select drag and drop saving

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jquery-select2

I am using select2 to select related tours / posts on our WordPress powered website, which works fine, however, I would like to have an option to manually drag and drop the selected values to change their order.

I've found a snippet online

```
    $(".select2").select2();

    var formData=[];
    $("ul.select2-selection__rendered").sortable({
      containment: 'parent',
      stop: function(event, ui) {
          formData=[];
          var _li= $('li.select2-selection__choice');
            _li.each(function(idx) {
              var currentObj=$(this);
              var data=currentObj.text();
              data=data.substr(1,data.length);
              formData.push({name:data,value:currentObj.val()})
         })
            console.log(formData)
      },
       update: function() {
            var _li= $('li');
            _li.each(function(idx) {
              var currentObj=$(this);
              console.log(currentObj.text());
              $(this).attr("value", idx + 1);
            })
       }
    });
```

which I've added to WordPress admin that seems to work, at least from a drag and drop perspective, however, once I update/save my post the values revert to their initial sort order.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWKBI.png)

Some expert help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are changing the order on the current instance only.

If you want to hold the change, then try saving the value of your order (in sessionStorage/ localStorage/ cookie/ database) and on page load, always read the default order as the stored order.